# Gradle task and sourceset

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I hope someone could help me understand how a Gradle task is associated to a source set. Given the following source set and task:

```
sourceSets {
    itest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output
        java {
    srcDirs("src/itest")
        }
    }
}

task itest(type: Test) {
    description = "Run integration tests"
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.itest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.itest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

My understanding is that testClassesDirs specifies the output dir for test classes and classpath specifies where to find the dependency classes at runtime.

But where does it specifies Gradle should compile code in src/itest and run the test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Gradle manual, it comes from the `java` plugin for Gradle.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#java_source_set_tasks

> For each source set you add to the project, the Java plugin adds the following tasks:

So, because you wrap your class paths in `itest { ... }`, the plugin creates the tasks for the compilation under that name.